# Does this formula for a sum of cosines has a name?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

On [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743100/why-are-these-sum-cos-and-csc-equivalent#2743123), Bernard kindly gave me the formula

$$\sum_{k=0}^R \cos k \theta = \frac{\sin \frac{(R+1)\theta}{2}}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}} \cos \frac{R \theta}{2}$$

He describes the formula as well-known. Does it have a name, so I can find a few pages relating to it?

Comment: It is an easy corollary of the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: There is no $k$ in your summation. Anyway add the series with $i\sin(k\theta)$ and then it is a geometric series $(e^{i\theta})^k$

Comment: I know no name. I simply learnt it when I was in last grade of high school.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange Trigonometric Identity. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800489/lagranges-trigonometric-identity)

Comment: Thank you. That link says Lagrange's identity is only valid for $0 \lt \theta \lt 2 \pi$. Is this true? I'm after a universal statement - or at least true for all real numbers.

Comment: it is true. If $\theta \notin [0,2\pi ]$ that is not a problem since $\cos \left( k\theta  \right)=\cos \left( k\theta +2n\pi  \right)$ and you can choose $n$ such that $k\theta +2n\pi \in [0,2\pi ]$.